# Include template file with different variable value on click - Symfony2/Twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm quite noob when it comes to communicating between js files, controllers, templates and at all when in comes to js and ajax.

I have different links like this:

```
<a class="details" data-index ={{i}}> Link 1 </a>
```

but on click they do not load another page, but instead open a mini page, which should have different variable for each link.

I want to do something like this:

```
$('.details').on('click', function(){
        var index = $(this).data('index');
        {% include 'MyBundle::information.html.twig' with {'var':index} %}
});
```

but in this way .js won't give the index variable to twig and I get error that index is not defined :(

How to fix this? This don't need to go through controller. Changing the 'var' value does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this is using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle), if for some reason you do not want to use that bundle you might do something like this:

```
$('#details').on('click', function(){
    var index = $(this).data('index');

    var $whereToLoadContent = $("#divid") ; //where you want to load data
    //__index__ is just a placeholder
    var routeWithPlaceHolder= "{{ path('route_name',{'var':'_index_'}) }}" ; 
    var routeToLoad = routeWithPlaceHolder.replace("_index_",index) ;


    $whereToLoadContent.load(routeToLoad) ;


});
```

Not sure if syntax is correct but hopefully you get the idea. Again I recommend you use FOSJsRoutingBundle if you will be doing this a lot.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a problem :S When I put this in a separate .js file, I get error that there is not route for /GET/{{, when I put it in the template file, again I get that index is not defined :(

Comment: Remember you need to create the route named route_name. 'route_name' is just an example it can be anything.

As to why you are getting index not defied is because I made an error. index is a js variable. The best way to do this I think is using the FOSJsRoutingBundle. That bundle has a function. I am going to make an edit with a not recommended way of doing this.